# Multi-column normalization with categorical values in opposite severity level

Tags: python, statistics, normalization, pca

I have a dataset with 5 features, 2 categorical (ordinal, 1-5), 1 categorical (nominal), 2 continuous.

For 2 categorical (ordinal):
1st variable has 5 as extreme
 
2nd variable has 1 as extreme

For 2 continuous:
1st variable higher value is worse
2nd variable higher value is best

Ultimately after normalizing I have to run a PCA on the dataset.
Need to conceptually understand my options before running PCA.

Any opinions/suggestions/comments are welcome.

Comment: [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont)

Comment: @HS-nebula My question is different from this.

Comment: Right, but they're related, giving you some of the options you have before you run PCA. There's also [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/is-there-factor-analysis-or-pca-for-ordinal-or-binary-data) that talks about ordinal data.